# How can we know "by inspection" the location of maximum deflection of a simply supported beam with a point load?

Tags: structural-engineering, beam, deflection

I am working the following problem:

> The simply supported beam shown in Fig. 12-12a is subjected to the
>   concentrated force **P**. Determine the maximum deflection of the
>   beam. *EI* is constant.
>
> [image]

The text later says:

> By inspection of the elastic curve, Fig. 12-12b, the maximum deflection
>   occurs at *D*, somewhere within region *AB*. Here the slope must be
>   zero.

Why does the author say that, by inspection, the maximum deflection occurs at *D*? How do we know that? He didn't show any work or explain why it should be at *D* and not somewhere else.

If I consider the maximum slope to occur at a point 2 m from *A*, then I will take EI(dv2/dx2) = 0, then my answer is, -2((x2)^2) + 12x2 -44/3 = 0, then x = 4.29 m ....

here's the full question . 
in hree , we can notice that there are 2 sets of slope equation that we can use . Which is equation 5 & 7 . 
In equation 5 , we will get 1.633 as in the working . ( the author use by 'inspection' the max deflection occur at region AB)

However , when as @Jmac stated , we dont know where is the position where the max deflection is located , how can we use equation 5 to solve ?

why We dont have to consider equation , which involve region DC ??? [image: 22]
in 
[image: 33]

solving equation 7 = 0 , i have x = 5.23 , 3 and  0.763  , which is correct ?

Comment: No, it says the maximum *deflection* occurs at D. Therefore the *slope* at D is zero. The slope must be zero by the "common-sense" argument that if it was not zero, a point close to D would have a bigger deflection than D. Or you can make a rigorous argument using theorems that are proved in a calculus course.

Comment: ya , i know that when the deflection is max , then the dy/dx is 0 ... I just cant understand why by inspection , the max deflection occur at D . is it possible that the max deflection occur at other point ? It's not stated earlier in the question that max deflection occur at D , so the author just  guessing only ?

Comment: $D$ is *defined* as the point where the maximum deflection occurs. Notice that the location of $D$ is defined as "somewhere within $AB$". I agree that using the term "by inspection" is odd, though.

Comment: then , can you show how to prove that the maximum deflection at D is within AB ?

Comment: Can  you  explain  why  the  maximum  deflection occur  at  D ( within  AB) ?  Why  the  max  deflection  not  occur  at  the  point where  the  force  P is  applied ?

Comment: For point loading, I think the max deflection only occurs at the point of loading when it's loaded at the centre (and both ends are supported).  Consider that the place you are loading, it's closer to one support than the other.  That means that it's closer to a point resiting the load, so the maximum deflection ocurs somewhere else.  The case of being loaded in the middle is a special case because you are the same distance from both supports, so the maximum deflection is at the point loading.

Comment: That means that it's closer to a point resiting the load, so the maximum deflection ocurs somewhere else. what do you mean by this ?  can you explain furthter ??

Comment: kelvinmacks - you seem to have misunderstood. See Wasabi's comment: D is *defined* as the point where maximum deflection occurs. When the author writes that, he has not yet determined the exact location of D, he just knows that it is between A and B.

Comment: @JMac , by saying that  it's closer to one support than the other. That means that it's closer to a point resiting the load, so the maximum deflection occurs somewhere else , Do you mean that since the force it'a applied near one end (C) , so , the maximium deflection will occur at another side , which is near point A ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks Not necessarily at "another side"; just further from the support.  Consider if you were to place the load just to the left of point C.  It couldn't really deflect the beam that much; there's a support right beside it.  It would bend the beam a lot though; so the maximum deflection would be somewhere to the left of the load.  The load is causing bending along with displacement.  This bending is what makes the beam deform more further to the left.

Comment: @JMac , by saying  Consider if you were to place the load just to the left of point C , It couldn't really deflect the beam that much; there's a support right beside it. It would bend the beam a lot though; so the maximum deflection would be somewhere to the left of the load , Do you mean the mean the maximum deflection in this case will occur near to point B ? If not , can you give an example that the maximum deflection is located near to B , when the force is applied near to C than A ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks Point B in the question is the load.  I only wanted you to imagine the load right beside the support so you could get a feel for what was happening (by putting it very close to the support we can exaggerate what is happening in the question).  I'm not sure what (if any) loadings near C would make a maximum deflection at B though.  This seems to go back to the original problem.  The textbook doesn't know where D is when they start the problem; they only know what characteristics it has (slope of 0).  The purpose of the question is to find the exact location of D based on P.

Comment: @JMac , pls refer to the attachment , in here , refer to the edited post .

Comment: @kelvinmacks I honestly don't really get where you're getting lost there.   They use equation 5 to solve for the location of D (by finding where the slope is 0).

Comment: @JMac , why the author sure that the maximum deflection occur at region AD ?(He use equation 5 to solve the problem)  why not DC ? Since , as you stated earlier , we dont know either the maximum deflection  will occur at region AD or DC

Comment: @kelvinmacks it says they know it occurs between A and B; not A and D.  The reason they knows it occurs between A and B is what we had been covering during the rest of this conversation.   We know it's to the left of the load (i.e. between AB) because of where it is relative to the support.

Comment: @JMac , what do you mean by We know it's to the left of the load (i.e. between AB) because of where it is relative to the support??? the support are both point a and  point C , right ? Why you said it's C only ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks I never said C is the only support.   A and C are supports.

Comment: Consider that the place you are loading, it's closer to one support than the other. That means that it's closer to a point resiting the load, so the maximum deflection ocurs somewhere else.         @JMac , the reason that the author think that the max deflection occur at region AD if we apply the P closer to C  is simply because this one ?  So , the maximum deflection will occur at another side which is AD , which is further from the force applied ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks we know it will occur in section AB; remember we don't actually know where AD is; we are trying to find the location of D.  But yes, because of the support reason I explained, we know D is to the left of B, so we knows it's in section AB instead of section BC.

Comment: @JMac , actually i want to ask why we will know the max deflection occur at region AB instead of BC ( I didnt ask why we actually know where is D without calculation)   ... But you seems to misunderstood me , btw , thanks for your ans

Comment: @kelvinmacks I figured; but you called it section AD by mistake so I wanted to make sure I didn't mislead you.

Answer (score 1):

Engineers, by design, are lazy. If you are looking at a beam, where you can see that under a given load it deflects most at a certain point, then you can say that it deflects most at that point. It's like when you have symmetry conditions to only have to figure out half of the numbers for a beam, and extrapolating.

Textbook writers say 'by inspection' when they can use their engineering intuition and what they believe to be common sense in order to save labor.

But if you only had the beam, some forces, and we knew that the beam would bend downwards, bottom out, and start to bend back up to the other end, it's intuitive that if you rolled a marble from either end of the beam, it would roll down and settle on the lowest point, where it had a max deflection and a slope of zero.

Now, if there was a beam with multiple forces pointing up and down, with the beam looking like a ride at Disney Land, then that would be a different story. Then, you would have to go through more calculations and really get that engineering intuition into action.

But most often, engineering intuition is knowing how to use the minimum computation for the required results.  The author simply said, there is only one global and local minimum, and said, "close enough for government work."